# Find the intertwiner of two equivalent group representations

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group. Let 
$$\{A(g)\mid g \in G\} \text{ and }\ \ \ \{B(g) \mid g \in G\}$$
be two equivalent unitary matrix representations of $G$. How do I find a unitary intertwining matrix $S$ for $A$ and $B$, ie., 
$$S A(g) = B(g) S$$

for all $g$ in $G$?